# Inserting space into string using ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, string, replace

I am using ArcMap 10.7.1.

I want to insert a space into a string between specific parts of the string using Field Calculator:

!FIELD! .replace("F'target", "F 'target")

Neither 'F' or 'target' are at beginning or end of string, those characters are in the middle of a string.

I run the calculation, and nothing happens.
I've tried to escape the single quote, but no difference.
Do I need a wildcard tag at beginning and end of the substring?

Answer (score 3):

No need for wildcards, the `replace()` method searches the whole string, as you can see if you test it out in the Python interpreter:

```py
>>> "Test string with F'target in the middle".replace("F'target", "F 'target")
"Test string with F 'target in the middle"
```

Double check that the exact string `F'target` does indeed appear in your field.

Comment: i looked closely and I found the problem, the first single quote was " ‘ " instead of " ' "
Not sure how that got there but that was it.